# Condition that differentiable function has continuous derivative

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

It's well known that if $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is a differentiable function then $f$ may not have continuous derivative i.e. $f\notin C^1$. Is there a minimal condition such that differentiable function becomes $C^1$ function?

Comment: Do you want a condition that when added to "$f$ is differentiable at $x=a$" implies that $f$ is $C^1$ at $x=a,$ or something that says if $f$ is differentiable at each point of some nonempty set $A$ (possibly satisfying some property, such closed and positive measure, or dense in the reals) then $f$ will be $C^1$ at each point of some (possibly different) nonempty set $B,$ or something else?

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Former case. Thanks.